# Potential PhD supervisor replied short but expressed interest, what to do next?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, supervision, correspondence

I wrote a relatively long email to a potential supervisor and they answered quite short, saying that they are delighted to hear of my interest in the program and they would be happy to work with me. I do not know how generic this answer is, but can you tell me what would be the good next step? Should I ask them for a skype meeting?

Thanks!

Comment: Where is this? In some places it means more than in others. It can also vary by field.

Comment: This is one of the universities of California and in humanities!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Word of caution: my answer below is based on my experience in Canadian Universities and may not apply to other countries.

The way I interpret this response is: your profile is interesting and you are encouraged to list this professor as one of the potential advisors on your application.

If you want further information regarding the lab's research, it seems you will have to initiate this. Just keep in mind that at this point, the professor is likely getting a lot of enquiries. This is the likely reason for the short reply. Some professors may (at this stage) decline extended conversations and refer you to their lab web page, while others will gladly take the time to talk to you. I would send an email thanking this person for their reply, letting them know that you intend to list them as a potential supervisor (if that is indeed your intention), and asking them if they think it is appropriate at this stage to discuss your remaining questions over mail or via skype.